# "@typescript-eslint" was conflicted between ".eslintrc.js" and ".eslintrc.js » @react-native-community/eslint-config#overrides[1]"

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I have this error, I got this error on compilation process:

```
"@typescript-eslint" was conflicted between ".eslintrc.js" and ".eslintrc.js » @react-native-community/eslint-config#overrides[1]"
```

My eslint configuration is:

```
module.exports = {
  root: true,
  extends: ['@react-native-community', 'plugin:storybook/recommended'],
  parser: '@typescript-eslint/parser',
  plugins: ['@typescript-eslint'],
  overrides: [{
    files: ['*.ts', '*.tsx'],
    rules: {
      '@typescript-eslint/no-shadow': ['error'],
      'no-shadow': 'off',
      'no-undef': 'off'
    }
  }]
};
```

Any solutions/fixes?

Answer (score 1):

1. If you are not using React Native, you may not need the @react-native-community/eslint-config. You can remove it from your project by running:

```
    npm uninstall @react-native-community/eslint-config
```

2. If you do need both configurations, you can merge them into a single configuration object in your .eslintrc.js file by:

```
    module.exports = {
      extends: [
        '@react-native-community',
        'plugin:@typescript-eslint/recommended',
      ],
      plugins: ['@typescript-eslint'],
      rules: {
        // Add any additional rules here
      },
    };
```

Comment: same issue it's not solved